# What's the proper way to use **kwargs?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a class like

```
class myClass():
    def filter(self, inplace = False, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if isinstance(value, str):
                value = "'%s'" % value
            query_str += " & %s == %s" % (str(key), str(value))

myObject.filter(param1 = value1, inplace = False)
```

When I run it, I get an error message:

> pandas.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'param1' is not defined

I don't really understand it, because the reason you use `**kwargs` is to be more flexible when it comes to parameters, right?

Comment: What happens when you run this: myObject.filter(inplace = False, param1 = value1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star) and \* (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters)

Comment: I don't think this is a dup of * and ** for parameters.  The OP's understanding of kwargs seems correct for python, the issue is the interaction with pandas.

Comment: I get this error message: pandas.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'param1' is not defined.
Sam, you maybe right. The issue may be related to pandas. What am I supposed to do then now?

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to show more code or a more realistic example.  I appreciate that you're trying to give us a [mcve], and that's good, but you've trimmed things too much.  No where in your code do you show anything to do with pandas, but your error is a pandas error.  I expect that if you look at that code in a python program without any pandas involved at all, it will work as you expect.

Answer (score -1):

inplace is a positional argument and must come before keyword arguments. Try

```
myObject.filter(False, param1 = value1)
```

Comment: It's totally not a positional argument.  In a user-defined function, any argument named in the parameter list can be passed by keyword, and if so passed, order does not matter.